# How can I pass component object to container in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My goal is to reuse modal from bootstrap in multiple components. I have a question how can I pass a component to container?

```
   <ModalContainer
      title="Password recovery"
      body="<LoginRecoverForm someprophere='' />"
   />
```

This gives an error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `ModalLoginRecover`.
```

Here's simple container:

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap/lib/'
var React = require('react')

var ModalContainer = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return { showModal: true };
  },

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
    browserHistory.push('/login');
  },

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
     <div>
        <Modal show onHide={this.close}>

         <Modal.Header closeButton>
           <Modal.Title>{this.props.title}</Modal.Title>
         </Modal.Header>

         <Modal.Body>
            {this.props.body}
         </Modal.Body>

       </Modal>
     {this.props.children}
     </div>
)}});

module.exports = ModalContainer;
```

Here's simple component:

```
import {Modal, HelpBlock, FormGroup, Button, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap/lib/'
var React = require('react');
import { Router, ReactRouter, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

var ModalContainer = require('../../containers/ModalDialog')

function FieldGroup({ id, help, type, placeholder }) {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={id}>
      <FormControl type={type} placeholder={placeholder}  />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
}

function LoginRecoverForm(){

  return (
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <FieldGroup
      id="formControlsEmail"
      type="email"
      placeholder="Enter your E-mail"
    />

    <Button type="submit">Recover!</Button>

  </form>
)};

var ModalLoginRecover = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
          <div>
              <ModalContainer
                title="Password recovery"
                body="<LoginRecoverForm someprophere='' />"
                />
          </div>
)}});

module.exports = ModalLoginRecover;
```

Comment: Not 100% familiar with react, but can't you do `body={<LoginRecoverForm>}`?

Comment: @blockhead ok sorry, you're right, post an answer, i'll mark it as solved. problem been in another place. But I still needed this answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSX is just javascript, you can pass it in as props, just like any JS expression:

```
<ModalContainer 
   title="Password recovery"
   body={<LoginRecoverForm someprophere=""/>}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
   <ModalContainer
      title="Password recovery"
      body={(() => {return <LoginRecoverForm someprophere='' />})()}
   />
```

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `ModalLoginRecover`. index_bundle.js:8887:10

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `ModalLoginRecover`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is pass the component as a child like this:

```
<ModalContainer
      title="Password recovery"
      body=""><LoginRecoverForm someprophere='' />
</ModalContainer>
```

React will put `LoginRecoveryForm` component at the place of `{this.props.children}` in ModalContainer

Comment: So sad you can't comment yet. I just want to put it `this.props.body` and what i want to have multiple props with multiple components?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply insert components between the tag. The inserted component will treated as default children prop. Like in this example code, `<Container>` is parent my component and I am trying to add `<Routes>...</Routes>` as its children.

```
const RouterProfile = () => {
    return(
        <Container>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<ProfilePage />} />
            </Routes>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Now, You can see in this below code that child component is called using children prop that we are recieving from parent. Or you can log in console and see what are the argument you are recieving.

```
const Container = ({children}) => {
    return(
        <div className="d-flex flex-column" style={{width:"100vw", height:"100vh"}}>
            <div class="flex-grow-1" style={{overflow : "scroll"}}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```